# Image Fitting Div CSS

Tags: css, image, html

Getting frustrated with this one..

http://www.gd-gaming.com/wordpress/player-news/

If you look at the title area, I have it seperated into two divs, one contains the player name, the other contains an img related to the players team.

The image HAS to be 325 px or it will not fit the front page correctly - see here (www.gd-gaming.com/wordpress)

I've tried using gradients, overflow.. nothing is getting that gradient to extend all the way into the other div...

Note: the team logo must stay on the right side or it ends up in the middle like the other ones.

```
#player {
    height:40px;
    width: 300px;
    float: left;
    border-top: 1px solid #6B6B6B;  
    border-bottom: 1px solid #6B6B6B;
}

#player h2 {
    font-size: 15px;
    margin: 0;
    padding-left: 8px;
    padding-top: 10px;
    color: #fff;
    font-weight: 100;
}

.jacksonville {
    float:right;
    height:40px;
    background-image: url(images/teams/jack.png); /* fallback */
    background-image: url(images/teams/jack.png), -webkit-gradient(linear, right top,   right bottom, from(#444444), to(#999999)); /* Saf4+, Chrome */
    background-image: url(images/teams/jack.png), -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #0E7D93, #0B515E); /* Chrome 10+, Saf5.1+ */
    background-image: url(images/teams/jack.png), -moz-linear-gradient(top, #0E7D93, #0B515E); /* FF3.6+ */
    background-image: url(images/teams/jack.png), -ms-linear-gradient(top, #0E7D93, #0B515E); /* IE10 */
    background-image: url(images/teams/jack.png), -o-linear-gradient(top, #0E7D93, #0B515E); /* Opera 11.10+ */
    background-image: url(images/teams/jack.png),  linear-gradient(top, #0E7D93, #0B515E); /* W3C */
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    width: 325px;
}
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Before we can help you though, we need some code. Show us what you've done so far. A great way to do this is [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/). We will also need some more explanation of how you want your site to look.

Comment: I need the gradient in .jacksonville to extend to the left into the #player div.. so it fills both divs.

Comment: i'm not sure but try background-size: cover;  http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_background-size.asp

Comment: Put the background image of jacksonville in the playertitle class.

Answer (score 1):

You will need to style the `playertitle` `div`. I recommend that you change it from an ID to a class so it will be something like this: `<div class="playertitle">...</div>` instead of `<div id="playertitle">...</div>`. (IDs can only be assigned to one element per page, classes can be assigned to multiple elements per page.)

Then, in your CSS use this code in the `.playertitle` class:

```
background-image: -webkit-gradient(
    linear, left bottom, left top,
    color-stop(0.15, rgb(11,82,94)),
    color-stop(1, rgb(14,125,147)) );
```

Play around with the color stops to find the correct gradient (I picked one that is pretty close to yours but I think it's just a little off)

Comment: This works great.. the only issue is. I have a different gradient/team logo pulled in for each post.. So while this works perfectly for the first post, the second post gradient shows up incorrectly. Is there a way for me to extend this from the jacksonville div?

Comment: Heres the jfiddle - Im using custom fields in wordpress to pull in each seperate "team logo image" http://jsfiddle.net/rtXKp/1/

Comment: if I extend .jacksonville to 625 pixels (the full width of the element) the gradient works fine.. however, the small logo gets placed into the center of the screen.. So what I need to do... is find a way to get the gradient from .jacksonville, to continue through the element.. when the width is only 325 px... Not sure if this is even possible lol

Comment: @excessive34 I see that you've done something with your website. It looks like your problem has been solved... Do you need any more help on this topic?

Comment: Eh the way I have it isnt as friendly as I would have liked it to be but yes, this works for now thanks for the help guys.